# where I am going wrong in this MySQL query for wordpress Mysql?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
   INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
           ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
   INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
           ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
        WHERE term_id = 1 AND taxonomy  = 'category';
```

I want to get the list of posts through this query. Can anyone can solve this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@steven spielberg:**

Your error was that you specified `wp_term_relationships` twice instead of specifying `wp_term_relationships` once and `wp_term_taxonomy` once. Here is a working query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
   INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
           ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
   INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
           ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 
              wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
        WHERE term_id = 1 AND taxonomy  = 'category';
```

However, if you are planning to use that within a `.php` file for use with WordPress I would recommend you use a different approach, such as using `WP_Query` and starting with this:

```
$term = get_term_by('id',1);
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'taxonomy'=>'category',
  'term'=>$term->slug,
));
print_r($query->posts);
```

You can find other arguments for `WP_Query` on the [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) Codex page *(the arguments are the same.)*  There are several other arguments you'll probably want to use to fine-tune your query.

Of course if you must use direct SQL for some reason then at least use the `$wpdb` object so you don't have to worry about prefixes, like this:

```
  global $wpdb;
  $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} 
           ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}
           ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = 
              {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id 
        WHERE 1=1
          AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = 1 
          AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy  = 'category'
SQL;
  $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Hope this helps.

-Mike